# Adding TypeScript to exsisting React Project (Not create-react-app)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have been looking everywhere for a place to tell me how to add tsx compilers to an existing react project.  This was not a create-react-app.  Is it possible to use both TSX and JSX files in the same project?  I don't want to do everything in TSX, but I definitely want to get some practice in and don't want to convert the whole thing.  Do you guys have any places I can go look for this?  Here is my webpack.config for reference (if you know a way I can add lmk)

Version:  "react": "^16.8.1",

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
module.exports = {


    devtool: 'inline-source-map',

    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html',
            filename: "./index.html"
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
            // both options are optional
            filename: "/static/cs/styles.css",
            chunkFilename: "styles.css"
        })


    ],

    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'static/js/bundle.js'
    },
    module: {

        rules: [

            {
                test: /\.s?css$/,
                use: [
                    "style-loader",
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    "css-loader",
                    "sass-loader"
                ]
            },

            {
                use: { loader: 'babel-loader' },
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            outputPath: '',
                        },
                    }

                ]
            },


        ]
    },

    devServer: {

        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),

    },


}
```

Comment: [Read this](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/pull/985#issuecomment-239145468,)